# Something is overriding my onchange script?

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, custom-options, drop-downs, option

I made a script that selects an option from a dropdown. The dropdown has `onchange` trigger and it trigger correctly when i run the script as a snippet (in a sandbox environment), but when i active the script on my Magento site the `onchange` script doesn't trigger?

This is my code:

```
<script>
function selectItemByValue(dropValg, value) {
  var denne = document.getElementById(dropValg);
  denne.value = value;
  denne.onchange();
  console.log(denne.value);
  console.log(denne);
}
</script>

<ul>
  <li onclick="selectItemByValue('bundle-option-132', 700)"> Click to change</li>
</ul>

<select onchange="alert('Content changed')" id="bundle-option-132" name="bundle_option[132]" class="bundle-option-132 bundle-option-select change-container-classname" wtx-context="276DE744-A364-4DD3-AEFC-0D9F9A9AAE19">
  <option value="">Udvælg...</option>
  <option value="875">Bianco</option>
  <option value="695">T400</option>
  <option value="697">T402</option>
  <option value="698">T403</option>
  <option value="699">T404</option>
  <option value="700">T405</option>
  <option value="702">T407</option>
  <option value="703">T408</option>
  <option value="704">T409</option>
  <option value="705">T410</option>
</select>
```

I made a code snippet here: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FJWGP8WR16DD

On my Magento site the `onchange` script looks like this: `onchange="bundle.changeSelection(this)"` but if i replace this with `onchange="alert(Something)"` the script still doesn't trigger.

I'm using an extension called OptionBundle that needs the `onchange` trigger to calculate the content of the next dropdown.
The `onchange` trigger works when choosing an option manually from the dropdown but not when choosing an option with JS?

The only other script I can see that's monitoring change on this dropdown is `prototype.js`, but I just can't see why this would conflict with my script?

Comment: can you please add your magento code?

Comment: @AbhishekPanchal how much code? The above example is the code used on my site except the onchange trigger which is `onchange="bundle.changeSelection(this)` and not the alert used in the example. Do you mean the PHP code? I'm not changing anything in the PHP? It's all JavaScript, but something is blocking/overriding the `onchange`trigger?

Answer (score 0):

you can try :

```
$('#bundle-option-132').bind('change', function (e) {
//your code here
}
```

Note: $ = jQuery

Comment: Hi.
I'm not quite sure on how to use your example?
I've tried:

    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('#bundle-option-132').bind('change', function() { alert('Yes')
     });
    });

but it haves the same problem. It only triggers when i manually click the dropdown on choose an option. When I choose an option from the dropdown with JavaScript, then content of the dropdown changes (it shows the right option), but no onchange script is triggered including the Jquery `.bind` script.

No `onchange` or `change` event listener seems to register when content is changed by JS?